# Getting drivers and their programs from a Windows 7 recovery USB

Tags: windows-7, drivers, installation, data-recovery, extract

I have an ASUS Laptop that came with an incorrectly installed recovery partition. After a lot of hassle, I ended up buying new recovery media from the third party ASUS recommended – which was also flawed (install looks as if it is running well until the screen flashes in huge, screen filling red caps ERROR and reimaging fails). ASUS has informed me that, although the USB recovery media is the only thing they can offer, it’s failure to function isn’t their problem. Product is out of warranty, there is only one company to buy the recovery media from (the same company that imaged it incorrectly to begin with) and the ASUS website does not have all the drivers/programs available.

So I have purchased a new copy of Windows 7 OEM and installed it. I am now trying to extract the drivers and driver programs from the USB. I know it can be done and that the USB media is intact enough for me to extract most, if not all of it. So far I have managed to open the driver location (.wim file) using 7zip and have installed them (from folder DriverStore\FileRepository) using dpinst.exe and a batch file. However, the drivers don’t seem to be actually doing anything and I am having difficulty finding the actual programs for the drivers (such as the program which will make all the FN keys work). I have checked the laptop’s system files (System32) and the driver files are there.

I started by following these two guides:

http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/how-can-i-extract-drivers-from-a-windows-7-recovery-disc/

https://forum.raymond.cc/threads/how-to-extract-drivers-from-vista-dvd-for-windows-7.15176/

but most of the .inf files under the en-US folder would not install through the device manager and the ones that supposedly did had no effect (in fact, it lets me install a driver for the CPU as many times as I want).

Thanks for taking the time to read this and I hope you can help!

Comment: If you had a functioning system, why did you not extract your drivers from your system rather than searching them on CD? Is it too late now?

Comment: I definitely agree with @harrymc in this scenario.  I always keep a [backup copy of the DriverStore](https://superuser.com/questions/29704/how-do-i-go-about-backing-up-saving-installed-device-drivers-in-windows/1199073#1199073) folder for each Windows computer on my home network, and that has saved me a *lot* of time during various Windows reloads throughout the years.

Comment: Why are you purchasing stuff?  All you needed was a Windows 7 installation media, and I have answered how you get one of those, and provided steps to make it possible to use with an OEM license.  I am confused why anyone would want to actually install ASUS software by choice.

Comment: harrymc , Ramhound - Running the recovery media wipes the system leaving it with nothing. So I had to buy a CD to install an OS from.

And no, Ramhound I am not going to start pirating software. As for “I am confused why anyone would want to actually install ASUS software by choice.” That is your opinion, and (as I have already stated that I want to use their program) is as helpful as telling me to switch to Linux instead.

@Run5k Thank you for the link, but as I mentioned in my post, I already used the DriverStore folder from my recovery media.

Comment: @Zack, I know that you mentioned that in your post.  I was simply trying to emphasize that it is a "best practice" to have a backup of your DriverStore folder from a fully functional Windows operating system (as opposed to recovery media) after you verify that every device has been properly installed.  That way, you *know* that it has all of your device drivers readily available within that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install the drivers after I spoke with a gentleman the other day who reminded me that I had “Show hidden files and folders” off.

I am posting instructions here for anyone else who stumbles upon this post with the same problem (This works for my ASUS recovery USB - other brands may or may not structure their USBs similarly):

1. Open "Folder Options" (type "Folder Options" in start search or "hidden" in start and click "Show hidden files and folders") select the "View" tab and toggle: Show "Hidden files and folders"
2. Check your hidden folders – I had 3. You are looking for a file called Driver64.wim . For me, it was in located at E:\K73SD_WIN7_64
3. Extract file Driver64.wim with 7zip (or any other program that can handle .wim files).
4. For me, the drivers I wanted were in E:\K73SD_WIN7_64\Driver64.wim\Software\ - they had their installers, so I ended up not needed any custom batch files or code. Just click and install what you want like any program.

Enjoy!

Comment: Glad to hear that it all worked out in the end!  As I said before, once you get all of the device drivers installed and configured I *strongly* recommend maintaining a backup copy of the fully functional DriverStore folder on an external hard drive or DVD-R.  As you have seen, it can save you a tremendous amount of time and effort in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have started such manipulations without first taking a disk
image of your system drive, just so that you could backtrack in case of error.

Now you have a problem that the CD you got has the wrong drivers, so it seems
that the ASUS drivers you need are not among the drivers that Microsoft
keeps on its CD, and also that the Microsoft generic drivers do not work for
your hardware. In short, a mess for which ASUS is well-known.

Your first stop for getting the right drivers should be the
[ASUS Support page](https://www.asus.com/us/support/). You should enter your computer details and download
and install all the drivers in the list that is displayed.

This should get you up and running. If it does not, then your last (slim)
hope is to use a driver-search product. Such products have generally
a bad name, so all I will give is a link to the article
[11 Free Driver Updater Tools](https://www.lifewire.com/free-driver-updater-tools-2619206). Treat with suspicion any driver
recommendation that these tools give you and try only the drivers that
you absolutely need. And I hope that this time you will take backups.