# Windows 10 breaks auto-rotation support

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure

I have a Vaio Z Canvas running Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (build 1709 16299.192). I made the mistake of performing a fresh install of Windows 10 which removed the official Vaio rotation driver (none of the official Vaio drivers fix the issue).

Right after running the "Reset this PC" tool, auto-rotation *actually works* as expected, however, after a few hours and a reboot later it seems to stop functioning. The "Lightweight Sensors Root Enumerator" seems to be the culprit as pre-reboot it is shown as "functioning normally", but after (I'm guessing a Windows update) it complains that "this device is no longer connected to this PC".

I've tried resetting the PC a second time, but this results in the exact same behavior. The lightweight sensors root enumerator and auto-rotate work for a little while and then stop without any warning after few hours and a reboot.

Is there anything I can do to fix this and get auto rotation on my tablet working again?

Comment: A friendly piece of advice:  prior to any type of Windows reload, [manually backup the DriverStore folder](https://superuser.com/questions/29704/how-do-i-go-about-backing-up-saving-installed-device-drivers-in-windows/1199073#1199073).  It can potentially save you a tremendous amount of time and effort.

Comment: @Run5k That is good advice and it's a pity not more people do it, but in my case it doesn't seem to be a missing driver issue, the relevant driver files are still on the machine (one in sys32/drivers along with some dlls in sys32/drivers/UMDF) and wiping it actually fixes the issue briefly until windows eventually forgets that the device is connected (still appears in device manager albeit with a notice saying 'device not connected') and I'm back to square one, I've had the exact same results three times in a row but I'm no closer to working out what's going on or where to go next.