# Computer only plays back sound through HDMI monitor

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi, speakers

I just reinstalled Windows 10 (HP Envy 700-109c desktop) and I have an ASUS monitor attached When I got the install up and running, I noticed that sound is only coming out of the awful monitor speakers, not the external ones I have attached to it. When I went to the sound devices, I only saw the monitor listed and a bunch of other disabled/disconnected devices (seemingly identical).

[image]

I've tried both speakers and headphones. The tower itself has two audio jacks, one in the back and one in the front, I've tried both of those too. I've tried reinstalling the audio drivers as well, I have 3. However, upon trying to reinstall the last one, I get an error message.

[image]

[image]

I never had any issues before I reinstalled Windows 10, and I know there's nothing wrong with the speakers or headphones. Al my drivers from HP are up to date as well. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For future reference, I always recommend [creating a backup](https://superuser.com/questions/29704/how-do-i-go-about-backing-up-saving-installed-device-drivers-in-windows/1199073#1199073) of the `%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\DriverStore` folder before you reinstall Windows.  It can save you a *lot* of time and effort afterwards!

Comment: Ooh, thanks,  didn't know about that.  I'll definitely do that next time

Answer (score 2):

Using [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_devices/idt-high-definition-audio-codec-not-working-on/570a5038-e48e-43f3-af75-95da61447c87?auth=1), I figured it out with a bit more research. I'm posting the solution here for all to see:

1. Select IDT High Definition Audio CODEC on Device Manager.
2. Select the Driver tab.
3. Click the Update Driver... button.
4. Select -> Browse my computer for driver software.
5. Select -> Let me pickup a list of device drivers on my computer.
6. Select High Definition Audio Device (Not IDT High Def...  this is important.) and click Next. A Warning message will appear, but reply Yes.
7. Windows has successfully update your driver software.